# Difference between \uncover vs \visible vs \only?

Tags: beamer, overlays

What are the differences between `\visible<>{}`, `\uncover<>{}` and `\only<>{}` in beamer/tikz?
At the moment I am using them interchangeably and could not understand their particular use cases.

I think one of them already assigns the space required for the object to be revealed and one of them reveals the object and required space gradually.

Can anyone once for ever clear this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a simple example where you can see the difference between the macros. `\visible` will reserve the space, depending on your settings `\uncover` can be dimmed on pervious overlays and `\only` is only present on the specified overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

text \visible<2>{text} text 

text \uncover<2>{text} text 

text \only<2>{text} text 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a more detailed explanation, see section `9.3 Commands with Overlay Specifications` of the beamer user guide https://texdoc.org/serve/beamer/0

Comment: Very good example. Thank you.. better than all those explanations in the beamer document. I just want to complete this answer by saying that you are showing the first slide and `\only`  does not occupy any space for its *text*. It was a bit confusing in the beginning for me.

Comment: @Puya yes, the content of `\only` is not present on previous overlays. It is not just that it doesn't occupy space, it just isn't there. This distinction is important to remeber if you use labels, make definition or increase counters within `\only`